# How to format a lua string with a boolean variable?

Tags: lua, string-formatting

I have a boolean variable whose value I'd like to display in a formatted string. I tried using `string.format`, but get something like the following for any choice of format option listed in the [language reference](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.format):

```
Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> print(string.format("%c\n", true))
stdin:1: bad argument #2 to 'format' (number expected, got boolean)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'format'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
```

I can get the boolean to display by adding a `tostring`,

```
> print(string.format("%s\n", tostring(true)))
true
```

but that seems rather indirect to this lua beginner. Is there an formatting option I've overlooked? Or should I use the above approach? Something else?

Comment: why use string.format?  Why not just print(tostring(true))

Comment: you can also not format nil, function, thread, userdata...

Comment: @Jane T Because it's part of a longer string, the example is pared down to the minimum.

Comment: That's fine,  then yes you will need to use tostring.

Comment: @sylvanaar - That's the sort of information I'm looking for -- can you point me to where that's documented?

Comment: @Michael You can find that information in the string.format reference: http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.format

Comment: @kikito - No, that info isn't there. That just has formatting options, while I was hoping to hear what sort of values *can't* be used with string.format.

Comment: Emm.. it says "numbers or strings". Everything else is implicitly not accepted.

Comment: I'm new at lua---I don't do implicit. ;)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Looking at the code of `string.format`, I don't see anything that supports boolean values.
I guess `tostring` is the most reasonable option in that case.

Example:

```
print("this is: " .. tostring(true))  -- Prints:   this is true
```

Answer (score 27):

In Lua 5.1, `string.format("%s", val)` requires you to manually wrap `val` with `tostring( )` if `val` is anything other than a string or number.

In Lua 5.2, however, `string.format` will itself call the new C function `luaL_tolstring`, which does the equivalent of calling `tostring( )` on `val`.

Answer (score 11):

You can redefine string.format to support an additional `%t` specifier that runs `tostring` on an argument:

```
do
  local strformat = string.format
  function string.format(format, ...)
    local args = {...}
    local match_no = 1
    for pos, type in string.gmatch(format, "()%%.-(%a)") do
      if type == 't' then
        args[match_no] = tostring(args[match_no])
      end
      match_no = match_no + 1
    end
    return strformat(string.gsub(format, '%%t', '%%s'),
      unpack(args,1,select('#',...)))
  end
end
```

With this, you can use `%t` for any non-string type:

```
print(string.format("bool: %t",true)) -- prints "bool: true"
```